# Render a FeatureCollection from a GeoJSON file with multiple types in Mapbox-GL-JS

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

We are currently loading layers into mapbox GL from geojson data. If our geojson has a feature collection that contains points and polygons, there does not seem to be a way to have mapbox gl show both because of how you need to set the type of layer.

Is there a way to have multiple types for a layer? It seems as if it can't handle multiple.

```
   map.addLayer({
    "id": "route",
    "type": "line", //THIS SEEMS TO BE THE LIMITATION
    "source": "route",
   });
```

Answer (score 5):

You are correct, GL JS cannot handle multiple types per layer.

You can, however, display multiple geometry types from a single source by creating multiple layers:

```
map.addLayer({
    "id": "route-line",
    "type": "line",
    "source": "route",
    "filter": ["==", "$type", "LineString"]
});

map.addLayer({
    "id": "route-point",
    "type": "circle",
    "source": "route",
    "filter": ["==", "$type", "Point"]
});

map.addLayer({
    "id": "route-fill",
    "type": "fill",
    "source": "route",
    "filter": ["==", "$type", "Polygon"]
});
```

Comment: Thanks Lucas - Will try this out!

Comment: How would one achieve this with a vector tile source? Is it possible? Instead of the geojson example listed above