# Loading geojson data into Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I can't seem to get my data to display on my map. The geojson file is huge so I am loading it an external source. My index.html file looks like this

```
<div id='map'></div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2VhbmRyYWFkbG96ZSIsImEiOiJjajA3cW1pOTcwMDA5Mndvd2hicHlmNWc1In0.7bt7sPXDoymYJyVDvVmqZw';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/seandraadloze/cj1dcc3ho00f82smkvjxp4frb', //hosted style id
    center: [24.530,-32.254], // starting position
    zoom: 14.5 // starting zoom
    });

    var url = 'http://bestersurveys.co.za/htmlsite/quintin.geojson';
    var source = new map.addSource()({
      data: url
    });

    window.setInterval(function() {
      source.setData(url);
    }, 1000);

    map.on('style.load', function() {
      map.addSource("markers", source);
      map.addLayer({
        "id": "markers",
        "type": "circle",
        "visibility": "visible",
        "source": "markers",
        "paint": {
          "circle-radius": 0.2,
          "circle-color": "#f3f3f3"
        }
      });
    });

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I am getting this error from the console

```
map.js:895 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addSource' of undefined
    at new e.addSource (map.js:895)
    at maptest.html:27
```

You can check out the map here - http://bestersurveys.co.za/htmlsite/maptest.html

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Sean

Comment: I'm guessing this part `var source = new map.addSource()({`. Remove the new keyword.

Comment: Hi mate, thanks. Okay that sorted the error, but still no data, my console now prints

Uncaught Error: Style is not done loading
    at t._checkLoaded (style.js:272)
    at t.addSource (style.js:372)
    at e.addSource (map.js:895)
    at maptest.html:27

Comment: Hmm, never encountered that one before. I found that putting everything between the `map.on('style.load'` could fix the problem, so your code is fired as soon as the styles are loaded.

Comment: I get a 404.3 error when I try to access http://bestersurveys.co.za/htmlsite/quintin.geojson.

Comment: I get a 404.3 error. No idea what that is but I will check into it to see if I can fix it and then get back to you guys here. Thank for helping up to this point.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for the extra error. I have fixed that. I am still getting this error in the console though.

style.js:272 Uncaught Error: Style is not done loading
    at t._checkLoaded (style.js:272)
    at t.addSource (style.js:372)
    at e.addSource (map.js:895)
    at maptest.html:27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my console now prints `Uncaught Error: Style is not done loading`

Move your `map.addSource()` call into the `style.load` event handler (see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200733/mapbox-error-style-is-not-done-loading).

Also, you are calling `addSource` wrong (see https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#addsource).

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2VhbmRyYWFkbG96ZSIsImEiOiJjajA3cW1pOTcwMDA5Mndvd2hicHlmNWc1In0.7bt7sPXDoymYJyVDvVmqZw';

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/seandraadloze/cj1dcc3ho00f82smkvjxp4frb',
  center: [-71.059568, 42.360482],
  zoom: 1
});

map.on('style.load', function() {
  map.addSource("sample", {
    type: "geojson",
    data: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chelm/grunt-geo/master/samples/postgis.geojson"
  });
  // one layer per GeoJSON feature type, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36927026
  map.addLayer({
    "id": "sample-line",
    "type": "line",
    "source": "sample",
    "filter": ["==", "$type", "LineString"],
    "paint": {
      "line-color": "white"
    }
  });
  map.addLayer({
    "id": "sample-point",
    "type": "circle",
    "source": "sample",
    "filter": ["==", "$type", "Point"],
    "paint": {
      "circle-radius": 5,
      "circle-color": "red"
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#map {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mapbox-gl/0.35.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mapbox-gl/0.35.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>

<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: Hey, thank for helping out here. I have rearranged the code and I think I am a step closer after your answer(still no data).

I do now get a 'source not defined' error on
source.setData(url);

Is this not set here: var url = 'http://bestersurveys.co.za/htmlsite/quintin.geojson';

Sorry for asking mate

Comment: Don't just copy my code, pay attention to the details. I don't call `source.set()` at all because that's not necessary.

Comment: Hi, I realized my mistake. Sorry. This seems to be working, but I still get a 'Input data is not a valid GeoJSON object. You can see it all live here - http://bestersurveys.co.za/htmlsite/maptest.html

Comment: *"Input data is not a valid GeoJSON object"* is a pretty specific error message. It means exactly what it says.

Comment: Yep, thanks for helping to this point though. Your answer did fix my original issue so I will mark it as the answer and then keep hacking at the geojson file. Thanks mate

Comment: I've looked at it, you're not missing much to a valid file. that being said, Think about not sending a huge file like that to the client. A assume that you are not showing all those data points at the same time anyway, so it makes a lot more sense to build the GeoJSON on the fly with database query results than to send a huge number of data points to the client and only ever show very few of them. Letting the server create GeoJSON with a proper serializing function will also solve your "invalid json" problem for good.

Comment: Hi man. I changed the way my client exported the files and I got it working now. Thank you for your advice regarding the files here as well. Really appreciate the effort.

Comment: Good to hear! What are you working with on the server side?