# Geojson Data Not Displaying in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mapbox-gl-js

The geojson data I'm importing in a React ref hook isn't displaying. I have the .geojson file in my project folder. I expect to see red circles representing the coordinates of the geojson data. I tried wrapping it in a map.on, and substituted different kinds of events like 'load' and 'style.load' but still nothing shows up. The data does however show up when I upload it to MapboxStudio, so I expect it's something wrong with my code and not the geoJSON data.

```
export default function App() {
  const mapContainer = React.useRef<any>(null);
  // const map = React.useRef<mapboxgl.Map | null>(null);
  const [lng, setLng] = React.useState<number>(-74.0632);
  const [lat, setLat] = React.useState<number>(40.7346);
  const [zoom, setZoom] = React.useState<number>(12);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // if (map) return;
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainer.current,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [lng, lat],
      zoom: zoom
    });
    map.on('style.load', function () {
      // if (!map) return;
      map.addSource('propertyData', {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: './jersey_city_HA.geojson'
      });
      map.addLayer({
        id: 'property-layer',
        source: 'propertyData',
        type: 'circle',
        paint: {
          'circle-radius': 8,
          'circle-color': 'red'
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: did you mean if (map.current) return;  this to be if ( ! map.current) return;   Note: the !

Comment: I updated the code to avoid those conditional checks. Still the geojson data isn't showing up.

Comment: add a minimal codesandbox example or update full component code.

Comment: Can you cross check https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/use-mapbox-gl-js-with-react/

Comment: That very brief tutorial in their documents does not go over how to implement addSource or addLayer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365722/loading-geojson-data-into-mapbox?rq=1 see if this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by replacing the path to the local data with the url to the same data but on my GitHub. ‍♂️